# LESS Mixin for Line-height

Tags: css, less

I am using this mixin to generate rem font-size with fallback pixel sizes, but to also generate a line-height that is 1.5 times the font-size.

```
.font(@size: 16px, @line: @size) {
@remfont: (@size / 10);
@remline: (@size / 10) * 1.5;
font-size: @size * 1px;
font-size: ~"@{remfont}rem";
line-height: @size * 1.5px;
line-height: ~"@{remline}rem";
}
```

The negative is that is requires me to enter a value for my line-height, although it will not be needed once compiled. My LESS using this mixin is as such:

```
.font (13, 10);
```

And results in this outpu:

```
font-size: 13px;
font-size: 1.3rem;
line-height: 19.5px;
line-height: 1.9500000000000002rem;
```

Is there a way to rework this mixin so that it will output a line-height that is 1.5 times my font-size, without needing to enter a value?

Comment: It looks like the mixin already does what you're asking. The `@line` argument isn't actually used.

Comment: `line-height:1.5;` (without unit) will make the line height 1.5x of the font size. No need to calculate anything.

Comment: The problem isn't the output. The problem is requiring myself, or anyone else to input a value for the line-height although it isn't actually used. Instead of `.font (13, 10);` it would be nice to use `.font(13);` and the result be the font size and line height.

Comment: You can't use one argument as the default for another, that's why you have to pass both values. But as @freejosh points out `@line` isn't actually used in the mixin so just remove it and pass the font size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. For now it seems that using a @string value works without requiring any more value than the singular. Mixin:

```
.font(@string) {
@remfont: (@string / 10);
@remline: (@string / 10) * 1.5;
font-size: @string * 1px;
font-size: ~"@{remfont}em";
line-height: @string * 1.5px;
line-height: ~"@{remline}em";
}
```

Stylesheet usage:

```
.font (14);
```

Output:

```
font-size: 14px;
font-size: 1.4em;
line-height: 21px;
line-height: 2.0999999999999996em;
```